# Angular routing updated with unknown values after an error in console

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I had opened a custom popup that got a console error due to an undefined value passed to the Angular Datapipe in interpolation in the HTML file. After that, I clicked on the close button to close that popup. The URL first changes to a correct path i.e.

```
http://localhost:4200/app/main/dashboard/search
```

but quickly changes into an unknown URL path containing some HTML attributes name and value.

On click of the close below is the navigation URL coded.

```
http://localhost:4200/app/main/dashboard/search
```

And this is the navigation that happens in between and then it finally routes back to the above path as that is the default path in the routing file

```
http://localhost:4200/?menu-close-btn=&miles=0&time=45&notes=#/app/main/dashboard/search
```

I am unable to find the reason how the values

```
'/?menu-close-btn=&miles=0&time=45&notes='
```

got added to the URL automatically. It happens only when this code breaks via Datapipe. I checked all the router navigations written and still have no clue from where this URL change is taking place.

Below is my routing config:

```
const MAIN_MODULE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'requests',
        outlet: 'secondary',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/requests/requests.module').then(m => m.RequestsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'financial',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/financial/financial.module').then(m => m.FinancialModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'report',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/reports/reports.module').then(m => m.ReportsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'databases/custom/add',
        outlet: 'db',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./modules/databases/modules/edit-custom/edit-custom.module').then(m => m.EditCustomModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'databases/custom/:id/edit',
        outlet: 'db',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./modules/databases/modules/edit-custom/edit-custom.module').then(m => m.EditCustomModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'databases',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/databases/databases.module').then(m => m.DatabasesModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'main'
  }
];
```

Comment: could you provide your routing module?

Comment: Added the routing config. Please check now.

Comment: maybe there is an error or in your search component

Comment: The search component works fine for every case.  This issue only happens when Datepipe throws an error in the console.